# How to extract the values from request input xml in jmeter

Tags: web-services, jmeter

I wanted to extract the value of `refid1` and `refid2` tags form the input xml in `Http request`. `refID1` and `refid2` values are generated at runtime using random number function .
please find below attached screenshot for the problem :

[Request tab snapshot from Jmeter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bHdz.png).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's in the request, how do you generate/send it?

Comment: @ user7294900 : using the random Number function ${__Random(0,10000)}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're generating the data, I suppose you have access to the XML request data.

So in this case, you can make those 2 fields variables extracted from CSV using [CSV Data Set config](http://You%20should%20use%20this%20plugin:%20%20-%20https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/overview%20%20%20Which%20you%20can%20install%20with%20jmeter-plugins%20download%20manager:%20%20-%20https://jmeter-plugins.org/install/Install/%20%20You%20can%20then%20use%20JMeter%20[CSV%20Data%20Set][1]%20to%20get%20data%20from%20a%20CSV%20and%20pass%20it%20in%20body%20of%20Websocket%20requests%20%20%20%20%20[1]:%20http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config).

If you're generating them using  JMeter [__Random](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) function, then you can use this syntax:

> ${__Random(0,10, MYVAR)}

And then use **${MYVAR}**

Answer (score 0):

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of your request
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   vars.put('request', sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue())
   ```
3. Add [XPath Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) after the JSR223 PostProcessor
4. Configure it as follows:

   - Apply to: JMeter Variable -> `request`
   - Reference Name: anything meaningful, i.e. `refId`
   - XPath Query: `//*[starts-with(local-name(), 'refId')]`

     [image: JMeter Xpath Extractor]
5. You will be able to access your "refId" values as `${refId_1}` and `${refId_2}` where required.