# How to extract data from AMQP request in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, amqp

I have used AMQP Publisher to publish the message in RabbitMQ then I use AMQP Consumer as listener. In the View Results Tree the messages from the queue in shown in the request tab of AMQP Consumer. My question is how to extract data from that request. I tried following the Bean Shell Post Processor but it seems it will only work on Http request. I tried to use JSR223 Post Processor and XPath extractor but it doesn't work as well. Any help?

I wanted to extract the documentId from the request. Here is the [Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coFnM.png) pattern.

I have already tried following links:
[Extracting value from jmeter post request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37740540/extracting-value-from-jmeter-post-request)
[how to extract value from request in Jmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31127129/how-to-extract-value-from-request-in-jmeter)
[How to extract the values from request input xml in jmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47069882/how-to-extract-the-values-from-request-input-xml-in-jmeter)

Answer (score 0):

1. The statement that you tried something without sharing the code doesn't make sense
2. Posting JSON data or code as image is not the best idea

---

Any reason to extract data from the request? Normally people know everything about the request hence don't require to extract anything from it. Even if they do - they should normally able to store the request data into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) and apply the relevant [Post-Processor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) to it.

Whatever, just in case here is the solution:

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) (if you really want to do this using the Post-Processor) as a child of the request
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   vars.put('foo', com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).value,'$..documentId')[0])
   ```
3. That's it, you should be able to access the extracted value as `${foo}` where required.

References:

- [JsonPath: Getting Started](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#getting-started)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)